# Random number relatively prime to an input

Tags: c, math, random, primes

What's a computationally sane way to, given a natural number `n`, generate a random number that is relatively prime to `n`?

I'm willing to sacrifice some randomness and coverage of all possibilities for speed. That is, if I only ever hit perhaps 75% of the possible (smaller) relative primes, that's fine.

Comment: What do you need the numbers for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in simple words:

```
unsigned random_prime(unsigned n){
     unsigned r = rand(), t;
     while ((t = gcd(r, n)) > 1)
         r /= t;
     return r;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

"I'm willing to sacrifice randomness and coverage of all possibilities for speed."
Given n, select n+1.

You're going to need to be more specific.

Comment: Or n-1. For hash tables something like this is possibly not a bad idea, and there is likely to be empirical work done (I seem to remember a mention of this in Algorithms in C++).

Comment: Fantastic answer.  I'm not even sure he needs to get more specific; you answered his question as written.

Comment: @user786653: good point about n-1. I guess that could add some more randomness to it. ;D

Comment: @Stephen: hah, yeah, I thought I did, too. Still, maybe he didn't mean what he actually asked for.

Comment: @Thomas Carpenter: On second thought n-1 will work for less natural numbers than n+1 :) (The relevant section for what I was thinking about in "Algorithms and Data Structures in C++", 1996 (old i know) is p.g. 144-, but they use N-2 but have a pre-selected list of primes, where N and N-2 are both prime and relatively prime)

Comment: Gah, not *all* the randomness! :) Lack of clarity + SO = a mess.

Comment: @andyvn22: Hah, I aim to please. ;D

Comment: now something real random, draw one random bit and according to that chose `n-1` or `n+1`.

Answer (score 6):

The probability that two random integers are relatively prime to one another works out to 6/pi^2 (in the limit, for large N), or approximately 61%.  So generate-and-test should
be a viable strategy -- the GCD calculation is about O(log n), and you will probably
get a result in 2 or 3 trials.

Comment: Good idea. You know, you could even put an upper bound on the running time of this by doing at most 3 tries, and then defaulting to either (n+1) or (n-1).

Comment: For us mathematically challenged readers, I'm curious how you know/found/ciphered the `6/pi^2` number.

Comment: +1 Generate and test is almost certainly cheaper than factoring the number, computing the totient, computing a random number below the totient, and mapping that back to relatively prime numbers below `n`. Even for the product of primes up to 23 the success rate is better than 16%, which is the worst case for 32 bit numbers.

Comment: The 6/pi^2 value for the probability of two random integers being coprime is a fairly well-known result in number theory, and is closely related to the "Basel problem", the Riemann zeta function, and the distribution of prime numbers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem